# How to reopen the app from inital activity rather from last used activity in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, exit, homescreen

I would like to reopen the app from default activity rather being called from last activity which is been used last active sometime ago.Kindly help me with a snippet to solve this issue .Thank you.

Comment: then on resume u need to clear all the activties

Comment: When launched, app starts from the activity that has `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` category in manifest. It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @M-WaJeEh Thank you for your reply,when I am running my app and I close it leaving last activity unclosed and on resuming it comes to the same activity where I left rather to default activity specified in manifest..

Comment: I assume you leave the app by pressing home button. In that case its perfectly ok for your app to be launched from the last seen activity. I suggest you not to change that behavior. Rather focus on handling your life cycle properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try calling finish() in the onPause() method